# Concatenating the result of a case statement to the value of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to concatenate the result of a case statement into another field of the table?
For example this is my table, This is just a random example.

```
first  second   third
----   ------   -----
one    two      three
uno    dos      tres
```

This is my part of my sql query

```
CASE 'some_expression'
   WHEN 1 THEN 'Monday'
   WHEN 2 THEN 'Tuesday'
   ELSE 'undefined
END AS days_of_week'
```

What I want is to concatenate lets say the result of the statement to one of the fields of my table. For example concatenating the result of the case statement with the 'first' column. So the result could be

```
days_of_week
------------
Mondayone
Mondayuno
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CASE 'some_expression'
   WHEN 1 THEN concat('Monday',first)
   WHEN 2 THEN concat('Tuesday',second)
   ELSE 'undefined'
END AS 'days_of_week'
```

Comment: wow I don't even know how I didn't think of that. Must be tired. Thanks a lot man